# Can there be a game where there are no opponents?

Tags: game-theory, cooperative-game-theory

I am considering a scenerio where all the players a in collaboration with each other in an attempt to maximize some profit. However, each player is not 100% sure of the strategy of other player so have to figure out the strategy of other player to play his own strategy to collectively maximize some profit.

Is this covered by game theory? i.e. there are no opposition or state of nature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a [**coordination game**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_game), players' interests are perfectly aligned, so there is no "opposition" in the ordinary sense of the word. The game has simultaneous moves, which means, at the time of decision, players don't know what the others would choose.